# Escape square bracket in Tcl_StringCaseMatch

Tags: tcl

I am using `Tcl_StringCaseMatch` function in C++ code for string pattern matching. Everything works fine until input pattern or string has `[]` bracket. For example, like:

```
str1 = pq[0]    
pattern = pq[*]
```

`Tcl_StringCaseMatch` is not working i.e returning false for above inputs. 
How to avoid `[]` in pattern matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `[]` are special characters in the pattern matching. You need to escape them using a backslash to have them treated like plain characters

```
pattern= "pq\\[*\\]"
```

I don't think this should affect the string as well. The reason for double slashing is you want to pass the backslash itself to the TCL engine.

For the casual reader:

`[]` have a special meaning in TCL in general, beyond the pattern matching role they take here - "run command" (like `` or `$()` in shells), but `[number]` will have no effect, and the brackets are treated normally - thus the string `str1` does not need escaping here.

For extra confusion:

TCL will interpret `]` with no preceding `[` as a normal character by default. I feel that's getting too confusing, and would rather that TCL complains on unbalanced brackets. As OP mentions though, this allows you to forgo the final two backslashes and use `"pq\\[*]"`. I dislike this, and rather make it obvious both are treated normally and not the usual TCL way, but to each her/is own.

Comment: Need to escape both bracket or just opening one ?

Comment: @AvinashKumar If TCL sees a `]` without a prefixing `[`, it assumes it's a regular character, and that's why it works. I would much rather an error be thrown.I think it's confusing, so I didn't add it to the solution, but as you say - it works.

Comment: @AvinashKumar You changed your comment inline. Your previous one was better - you only have to escape the first one, but see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for quick help.